# NDVI values to image conversion

Tags: arcmap, ndvi

I have a column of NDVI values of several centroid of pixels and relevant longitude/latitude associated with it.
I want to convert this table to a raster image in ArcGIS 10.4.1. I know the conversion of a NDVI image to an NDVI table but not the other way around.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

These two solutions assume that your NDVI file is a regular grid (the centroids of the raster). There are two options, they require either an Advanced License or 3D / Spatial Anayst.

**Option 1: Advanced License /Standard License With Spatial or 3D Analyst Extensions**

Plot your centroid "pixels" as points in ArcMap using the Latitude and Longitude coordinates using the **"Add XY Event"** tool. Export this point file as a shapefile to a directory on your PC. Ensure you define the projection of the point file as the appropriate geographic coordinate system (assuming the Lat and Long are in degrees).

**Re-project** the point file to a projected / measured coordinate system (metres or feet).

In the Toolbox, Open the **"Conversion Tools" -> "To Raster" -> "Point to Raster"**
Choose the point file as the input, the value field is the field containing NDVI, select an output location for the raster, cell assignment and priotrity field can be left as default. Cell size is the distance between the points (so this only will work if the points are in a consistent grid.

The result is a raster containing the NDVI Values.

**Alternative Option 2: Standard License Without Spatial or 3D Analyst Extensions**

Plot your centroid "pixels" as points in ArcMap using the Latitude and Longitude coordinates using the **"Add XY Event"** tool. Export this point file as a shapefile to a directory on your PC. Ensure you define the projection of the point file as the appropriate geographic coordinate system (assuming the Lat and Long are in degrees).

**Re-project** the point file to a projected / measured coordinate system (metres or feet).

Buffer the points by half the distance between the points 
Use the "Minimum Bounding Geometry" Tool with the **"Geometry Type"** set to **"RECANGLE_BY_WIDTH"** and the **"Group Options"** set to **"List"** and the **field** containing the NDVI Value.

The output will be a polygon grid containing the NDVI values as a field.

This next part - I havent found a tool that will convert a polygon to raster in ArcMap. QGIS however has a useful tool called **"Rasterise"** that will convert the polygon you have just created into a Raster.

Add the polygon to QGIS, select the **"Raster" menu -> "Conversion" -> "Rasterize"**
Choose the polygon as the input, the field containing the NDVI values (must be a number) and an output location. Everything else can stay default.

You will have a raster containing the NDVI values from your points.

Comment: Good stuff. Glad it worked